# What is being meant with 'contains input string'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I'm working on a homework assignment. It is a node.js application that is the beginning of a user management system. I am having trouble 'translating' one of the sentences in the assignment. It says 'Users should be matched based on whether either their first or last name contains the input string.' I am a beginner with JavaScript, Node.js and everything else, so I am not sure how to interpret 'input string'. Any clarification on this would be appreciated.

Comment: If the input string is `"ell"` then we could say that: **1.** the string `"Hello"` contains the input string `"ell"`. **2.** the string `"World"` does not contain the input string `"ell"`.

Comment: The term _input <something>_ generally refers to something provided by whoever uses the application. So the **input string** is provided by the user of the application to the the application. And the application uses that string.

Comment: It sounds like you have a function getting an input "string" that you'll have to use to match to one of your user names.

Comment: If you don't understand your assignment you need to ask your teacher, not the internet

Comment: Thank you for all the positive reactions and trying to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your homework application will contain a list of users, including their first and last names, along with an input element `<input/>` that works as search filter.

My guess is that you should implement the filtering functionality, i.e. the user types something, e.g. "ell", into that input, and your application should return all names having "ell" in either their first or last names. In this case, "ell" would be the input string.

Comment: There is no `<input/>` element in nodeJS.

Comment: That is correct. I was thinking in the Javascript-UX-box, my bad! Nevertheless, the idea of "user provides textual input" still applies.

Comment: Thank you for thinking along!